# If $\kappa$ is the $\alpha<\kappa$-th inaccessible cardinal, then the regular cardinals below $\kappa$ form a non-stationary set

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

How can I prove that if $\kappa$ is the $\alpha<\kappa$-th inaccessible cardinal, then the set of all regular cardinals below $\kappa$ is nonstationary? Is it because the set $\{x: x\text{ is a singular strong limit cardinal smaller than }\kappa\}$ is a club in $\kappa$?

Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: Yes, if the regular cardinals below an inaccessible are stationary, then so are the inaccessibles below it, since the strong limits form a club (if that's what you were getting at with your last sentence). Thus there are $\kappa$-many (since $\kappa$ is regular, per Asaf's answer).

Comment: Thank you your answer is good too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's easier to do it by contrapositive.

Since $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, the set of strong limit cardinals is a club below $\kappa$. If the regular cardinals form a stationary set, the intersection with the aforementioned club is stationary. So there is a stationary set of inaccessible cardinals.

In particular, there are unboundedly many inaccessible cardinals below $\kappa$, so it has to be the $\kappa$th inaccessible.

Comment: Thank you really helpful